# Can the recipient if my international wire transfer request my ID?

Tags: international, transfer

I sent a large amount international wire transfer in EUR to a merchant (business account) in France. On my end I see the transaction as "complete" in my bank. The recipient asked for a copy of my ID. Is that typical? Will he need a copy of my ID to be able to receive the transfer? Is it France regulation or receiving bank regulations to request a copy of the sender's ID? or do I refuse?

Comment: Did they give a reason for wanting to see your ID?

Comment: @TomRevell: I asked the receipient and they said because of my Arabic name. I'm not sure what that means. Is it because of an Arabic name and a US account? Not sure.